# Format a datastructure for sending an adaptive card with at mention

Tags: json, graph, adaptive-cards

I've been fiddling with formatting a (json) data structure to send an adaptive card to a teams channel using Axios. So far I did managed to send an adaptive card. But I thought it would be nice to "at" mention the channel to get everyones attention.

This is what I came up with:

```
    const card = {
        "title": "Bericht voor de gehele groep.",
        "subtitle": `<at id="0">General</at>&nbsp;Hello there!`,
        "text": data.message,
    };
    const message = {
        "subject": null,
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<attachment id=\""+guid+"\"></attachment>"
        },
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": guid,
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail",
                "contentUrl": null,
                "content": JSON.stringify(card),
                "name": null,
                "thumbnailUrl": null
            }
        ],
        "mentions": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "mentionText": 'General',
                "mentioned": {
                    "conversation": {
                        "id": generalid,
                        "displayName": 'General',
                        "conversationIdentityType": 'channel'
                    }
                }
            }
        ] 
    };
```

First I create a card. A simple one with the at tag in the subtitle. The at should have an id refering to a mention in the message.
The thing that gets me is the id in <t tag (in the card). It gets messed up with a bunch of escapes for the quote marks.

```
data: '{"subject":null,"body":{"contentType":"html","content":"<attachment id=\\"[guid]\\"></attachment>"},"attachments":[{"id":"[guid]","contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail","contentUrl":null,"content":"{\\"title\\":\\"Bericht voor de gehele groep.\\",\\"subtitle\\":\\"<at id=\\\\\\"0\\\\\\">General</at>&nbsp;Hello there!\\",\\"text\\":\\"is dit een kaart?\\"}","name":null,"thumbnailUrl":null}],"mentions":[{"id":0,"mentionText":"General","mentioned":{"conversation":{"id":"[channel_id]","displayName":"General","conversationIdentityType":"channel"}}}]}'
```

I guess JSON.stringify is responsible for this. But the content in the attachement should be JSON encode (in my experience).

Any idee how I should format the card NOT to get all those escapes?